# How to add tilt effect to LongListSelector?

Tags: button, windows-phone-8, longlistselector, tilt

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 application. In this, I want to add tilt-effect to all my controls (Button, LongListSelector, etc). Could you please tell me how to add tilt effect in Windows Phone 8 Application controls?

Answer (score 3):

Try putting TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="true" in the Longlistselector.

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector Name="resultList" Grid.Row="1"
            DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResultItemTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TwitterCollection}"
            ListFooter="{Binding}"
            TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="true"/>
```

Add this in the constructor of the cs page of your xaml.

```
TiltEffect.TiltableItems.Add( typeof( LongListSelector ) );
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please do a little more research yourself, a simple [*Google-search*](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20phone%20tilt%20effect) got me this:

- [**Control tilt effect for Windows Phone**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941094%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

And from that article, you can go to:

- [**How to use the control tilt effect for Windows Phone**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941108%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)